# FullCalendar V3 more events pop over scroll bar not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am interested in hearing from anyone who has experienced this problem in the past or has any idea what the cause might be.

I am using the FullCalendar V3 library and when I click on the more events pop over the scrollbar does not work and I cannot scroll down to see all of the events.

The scroll bar does not work on Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 however I have checked it on Firefox 84.0.2 and it scrolls ok on that browser.

I have not changed any of the library code and I have the impression it is some JavaScript that is the cause but would not know where to start.

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Below is the popover in question:
[image]

Comment: fullCalendar 3 is quite an old version and isn't developed anymore. If it has bugs, they are unlikely to be fixed. Upgrade to the latest version and see if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused due to a chrome smooth scrolling issue. Assuming you have no control over the browser side and therefor cannot disable that feature. Applying this to the scrolling container inside the popup should fix the issue.

```
pointer-events: auto !important
```

Note the selector I used was.

```
.fc-more-popover .fc-body.fc-widget-content .fc-event-container
```